# Why doesn't the layout design preview get displayed on my Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I don't know if it's me or something but I can't place a simple text or a button in design mode in Android Studio

[image: Screenshot here]

If it helps, this is the code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.45"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Test" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Which version using of android studio

Comment: press on that red exclamation mark or press key E on keyboard, while you layout is open. The red exclamation mark shows there is an error in your layout.

Comment: My version is Android Studio 3.1.3 and the errors is : 

Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error. 

/ and /

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Comment: Change **Theme in Editor** from **App Theme** to anything with **.NoActionBar** (e.g. AppCompat.NoActionBar). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Problem solved by @I_A_Mok*

> **"Change Theme in Editor from App Theme to anything with .NoActionBar (e.g. AppCompat.NoActionBar)."**

and this is working! thanks a lot! :D

Comment: How do you change that in editor? What do you mean by editor? Also, default theme already has NoActionBar. Example: <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

Comment: I mean (i don't have the software now)editor is the visual tab, you have the function App Theme.

Answer (score 0):

You messed up your Button's constraints:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
android:visibility="visible"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.45"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
tools:text="Test" />
```

In particular:

- `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"`
- `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"`

That's making it not show up in your Design editor.

Fix it to be:

- `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`
- `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`

Comment: after changes, still doesn't work :/ nothing is displayed

Answer (score 0):

If that's the full layout you're missing the closing tag for the ConstraintLayout at the very bottom:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.45"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Test"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```