# Created a simple button in Android Studio and nothing appears

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new on Android Studio and I just want to create a button who open an URL. For that, I have just created a basic activity from the software. When I try to drag and drop on the design nothing is happening.

[Here it is the screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swKc6.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your XML as text rather than as an image? It's very hard to read and understand otherwise. Please add it as [an edit to your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51286681/edit)

Comment: Yes sorry, this is good now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a website when a Button is clicked in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026349/how-to-open-a-website-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-android-application)

Comment: I want to say it's can be helpful if i can see where is the button on my project before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by @I_A_Mok with this problem: [Why doesn't the layout design preview get displayed on my Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276219/why-doesnt-the-layout-design-preview-get-displayed-on-my-android-studio/51347310#51347310)

"Change Theme in Editor from App Theme to anything with .NoActionBar (e.g. AppCompat.NoActionBar)."

and this is working! thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

There is a

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

missing on your button. You defined it with 0dp width, so it will scale first if you define left and right constraints.

0dp width or height inside a `ConstraintLayout` means, that the View will take as much space as possible with the defined Constraint attributes. You missed one for the width scaling, so it will stay 0dp.

Comment: I have added that but nothing happened again

Answer (score 0):

If problem persist just follow these steps:

**File> Invalid cache/Restart > Invalidate and Restart**

It will then surely work

**Update :**

I get this problems too but it works by **Choosing another theme**